# how to use document.getElementbyId in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

i want to run javascript in PHP but this code isn't not working at all for me.

```
if(!mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
     'document.getElementById("console1").innerHTML += "Query did not work";',
     '</script>'  ;

    }
```

Comment: i tried it works for me , you may forgot to add `console1` as id for some element in your page or the condition hasn't been true

Comment: can you post the complete page? also keep in mind that php is run on server side whereas javascript is run on the client

Comment: @wodka i am calling this php file from html page using ajax.

Comment: @Ali i have rechecked and everything is in place

Comment: @wodka yes i am aware of that, i am using xampp

Comment: if you are calling it with ajax there should be a return value -> per default no script of the result is evaluated

Comment: @wodka is there any other way of calling php file from html

Answer (score 3):

Replace those `,` with `.` to chain a string.

```
if(!mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">' . 
      'document.getElementById("console1").innerHTML += "Query did not work";' .
      '</script>';
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use " in php, this worked for me!

```
echo "<script> 
       document.getElementById('console1').innerHTML += 'Query did not work'; 
      </script>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Try the Heredoc Notation:

```
<?php
    echo<<<HTML
    .
    .
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("console1").innerHTML += "Query did not work";
    </script>
    HTML; 

//[*Note that echo<<<HTML and HTML; has to be on the very left side without blank spaces]
```

Answer (score 1):

since it is done with ajax try something similar to this:

```
<?php
    if(!mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        http_response_code(500);
        die(['error' => 'Query did not work!']);
    }
?>
```

and in your frontend code something like:

```
<script>
    $.get('your/query/path?query=...', function() {
        console.log('executed');
    }).fail(function(result) {
        $('#console1').append(result.error);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: its actually a GET request from ajax!

Comment: so replace $.post with $.get and skip the 2nd parameter - still the same systematic